# Could somebody help me translate what these bookmarks say?

Tags: translation, meaning

My boyfriend got me a small box of bookmarks off the internet, however they are all in Chinese. I have tried translating them through Google Translate but had no luck as it is not picking up all the characters. I would love to start using them as they are very cute but I'm hoping they do not accidentally say something inappropriate.

I have attached the photo of the bookmarks below.
[image]

Thank you in advance for the help!

Comment: From left to right 1. 养喵不读书，不如养头猪 2. 读书使喵充实 3. 阅读是心灵の(的)旅 行 4. 享受读书/de/(的)乐趣 5. 书是萌的泉源 6. 书是智慧的钥匙 > Now you can try Google Translate and come back and ask what you don't understand.  BTW, nothing inappropriate.

Comment: You may be interested to know that cats, the feline, in Japanese culture symbolizes "good luck", or all things positive. Thus you see the cat figurine maneki-neko (招き猫) or “beckoning cat” in shop windows, restaurant premises and now, bookmarks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Google Translate:

1. 养喵不读书，不如养头猪 - Raising a cat is worse than raising a pig
2. 读书使喵充实 - Reading enriches the cat
3. 阅读是心灵の(的)旅行 - Reading is the journey of the soul
4. 享受读书/de/(的)乐趣 - Enjoy the pleasure of reading
5. 书是萌的泉源 - Books are the source of cuteness
6. 书是智慧的钥匙 - Books are the key to wisdom

- Only #1's translation is bad, 养喵不读书，不如养头猪 means "Raising a cat but not read, might as well raise a pig instead"
- 喵 = 'meow' . It replaced the actual character for 'cat', which is 貓

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! It's cute that the writings are both about reading and cats :D